# showing that WiFi connected but system is offline on 16.04 LTS ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, bug-reporting, iwlwifi

I changed my OS 14.04 to 16.04,after installing showing that WiFi network  connected but internet is not accessible(i tried to ping which results unreachable).

```
ifconfig results

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:1b:6b:07  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:128960 (128.9 KB)  TX bytes:128960 (128.9 KB)

wlp2s0b1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:4b:f5:51:cc:7c  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2405:204:d308:6386:864b:f5ff:fe51:cc7c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::864b:f5ff:fe51:cc7c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2405:204:d308:6386:dd9e:bb6a:f58d:dc71/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6863 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6515015 (6.5 MB)  TX bytes:811757 (811.7 KB)
```

How can i solve this issue

Comment: Can you provide some additional information such as your `ifconfig` output and the `ping` results?

Comment: i tried ping 8.8.8.8 ,and results host unreachable@OwenHines

Comment: Okay, well can you still put the output of ifconfig in your question?

Comment: Edited my question with `ifconfig` results @OwenHines

Comment: i can connect internet through mobile hotspot

Comment: Have you tried connecting your phone to the WiFi and testing it on there? If it doesn't work on there, just try and reset your router.

Comment: phone can connect with router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46363/discussion-between-owen-hines-and-user214306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the command `iwconfig`
 then results

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"JFi2518A0E"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: C8:D7:79:51:8A:0E   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

then executed these commands to up wlp2s0b1

```
 sudo ifconfig wlp2s0b1 up
service network-manager restart
```